# Why Bash test case didn't reflect the command's exit status consistently?

Tags: bash

The test case fails despite the function's exit status:

```
#!/bin/bash

fun() {
    return 0
}
fun && echo "true" || echo "false"                        #result: true
[[ `fun` ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"                #result: false
```

Testing with echo command we can see that the exit status didn't change the consequences as we would expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "orange" 1>/dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"  #result: true
[[ `echo "orange "` ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"     #result: true

echo 1>/dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false"           #result: true
[[ `echo ` ]] && echo "true" || echo "false"              #result: false
```

What can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using backticks, you get the **output** of the function. There is no output. The test `[[ "" ]]` is "false" because that tests for the non-emptiness of the single string argument.

Looking at `help test` at a bash prompt we see:

```
String operators:

  -z STRING      True if string is empty.

  -n STRING
     STRING      True if string is not empty.   <== this is you
```